# pass a woocommerce product name to contact form7?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-contact-form-7

i want to pass the product name to contact form as a parametre
there is a plugin do that but it open it in poppup and thats i don't want
i want it to open a form
this is the Plugin: WooCommerce Quote or Enquiry Contact Form 7
and i find a short code that do perfectly but the button created  i wanna renamed to 'DEMANDE DEVIS'
and nothing change else
or i wanna this short code work on the add_to cart_button
// add inquiry button into every product
// we use the same hooks as before, to insert the new content on the same spot
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'prfx_add_inquiry_button', 10); // catalog page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'prfx_add_inquiry_button', 30); // single product page
function prfx_add_inquiry_button() {

```
$current_product_id = get_the_ID(); // get ID of the current post
$current_product_title = get_the_title(); // get the title of the current post

$product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id ); // get the product object

// create a button for variable/variant products
if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations(); // get all available variations of the current product

    if ($variations) {
        foreach ($variations as $variation) {

            if ($variation['variation_is_active'] == 1) {

                echo '<div>';

                // use this to see all available data
                // print_r($variation);

                $variation_price_html = $variation['price_html']; // variation price html, for example "€150,00 incl. vat"
                $variation_id = $variation['variation_id']; // variation ID, for example "2006"
                $variation_title = get_the_title( $variation_id ); // variation title, for example "Beanie with Logo - red, medium"

                // we create a button for each single available variation
                echo '<a href="'.home_url('/demande-devis').'/?product-title='.$variation_title.'" class="button">';

                    echo $variation_title; // show title
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo $variation_price_html; // show price html

                echo '</a>';

                echo '</div><br>';

            }

        }
    }

// create a button for simple products
} elseif ($product->is_type( 'simple' )) { 

    echo '<a href="'.home_url('/demande-devis').'/?product-title='.$current_product_title.'" class="button">';

        echo $current_product_title;

    echo '</a>';
}
```

}

please heeeeeeeeeeeelp

Comment: i do it but still problem the button that i added it appear on every product on list product page i want only in simple product page please help

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'prfx_add_inquiry_button', 10); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'prfx_add_inquiry_button', 30); 
function prfx_add_inquiry_button() {
    $current_product_id = get_the_ID(); // get ID of the current post
    $current_product_title = get_the_title(); // get the title of the current post
    $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id ); // get the product object
    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations(); // get all available variations of the current product

Comment: if ($variations) {
     foreach ($variations as $variation) {
      if ($variation['variation_is_active'] == 1) {
          echo '<div>';
    $variation_price_html = $variation['price_html']; 
    $variation_id = $variation['variation_id']; // variation ID, for example "2006"
    $variation_title = get_the_title( $variation_id );
                 echo '<a href="'.home_url('/demande-devis').'/?product-title='.$variation_title.'">';

Comment: echo("<button style=background-color:'green'; onclick=\"location.href=.home_url('/demande-devis').'/?product-title='.$current_product_title.\">DEMANDE DEVIS</button>");
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div><br>';
                } } }
    }elseif ($product->is_type( 'simple' )) { 
       echo '<a href="'.home_url('/demande-devis').'/?product-title='.$current_product_title.'" >';
echo("<button style=background-color:'green'; onclick=\"location.href=.home_url('/demande-devis').'/?product-title='.$current_product_title.\">DEMANDE DEVIS</button>");
        echo '</a>';
    }}

Comment: please do not use comments to add additional code...edit your question and insert your updated code.

Comment: Use the [is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#a-single-post-page) conditional tag to single out your product page on which you want your button to appear